# Cannot import ctypes on Linux

Tags: python, ctypes

I have Linux Ubuntu x64 14.04 with Python 3.4 installed (default installation by Ubuntu).
If I open CudaText text editor, it cannot import `ctypes` in console:

```
>>>> import ctypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyFloat_Type
```

Seems like Py3.4 installation is not full? Why it cannot load ctypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Debian Linux distros such as Ubuntu, Python extension modules are built assuming Python's symbols are loaded globally, so they don't explicitly list the Python lib as a requirement in the ELF header. An embedding application that links dynamically needs to load the Python shared library to the global symbol table, e.g. `dlopen("libpython3.4m.so", RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW)`.

The author of the [CudaText](https://github.com/Alexey-T/CudaText) editor is using [Python for Lazarus](https://github.com/Alexey-T/Python-for-Lazarus). I presume this uses [dynlibs](http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/tags/release_3_0_0/rtl/unix/dynlibs.inc). As you can see in the source, it does not call `dlopen` with `RTLD_GLOBAL`. The default is `RTLD_LOCAL` (0).